# Disabling copy paste option for UITextField will causes app reject?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, appstore-approval

Disabling copy paste option from UITextField will causes app reject?

I am using the method which was following

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender{
if (action == @selector(paste:))
    return NO;
return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
 }
```

Awaiting for reply.....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's app store review policies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you are using a method that is almost documented (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/AddingCustomEditMenuItems/AddingCustomEditMenuItems.html) I don't think there will be any issue with the app being rejected or whatever...

As the documentation says :

> The edit menu is a contextual menu that is displayed to offer commands
>   that can be performed on a selection such as a word in a text view or
>   an image. The edit menu is an integral part of copy, cut, and paste
>   operations, for which it displays (potentially) the commands Copy,
>   Cut, Paste, Select, and Select All. However, you can add custom menu
>   items to the edit menu to perform other kinds of actions on
>   selections.

Here the word

> potentially

might help you decide whether or not to do it. I would think you'd have no problem using the `@selector` stuff for disabling the copy/paste commands...

Furthermore, this question

> disabling copy/paste

has been asked so many times and nobody even cared about saying

> be careful, this will prevent your app from being approved on the
>   App Store

So, as I said, I personally do not think this will cause any issue.